# Difference between HttpClient and Unity's UnityWebRequest/WWW API

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, dotnet-httpclient

Unity now supports .NET 4.5 and I'm able to use the `HttpClient` class from the `System.Net.Http` namespace. That is great since I have existing client libraries which are therefore easy to reuse.

Does anyone know the internal **difference between** using the **mono HttpClient** and **Unity's own networking** classes?

I'm afraid that the HttpClient is not as optimized for the different platforms and might therefore cause trouble or be slower.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are many differences between the two.

- `UnityWebRequest` won't allow you to use change some headers. With `HttpClient`, you can change almost any header.
- `UnityWebRequest` is made to be used without worrying about threads or async stuff. All you do is use coroutine to wait for the request. The whole thread stuff is already done for you on the native side.
- Some platforms don't support anything from the `System.Net` namespace. One of this is `WebGL`. This means that `HttpClient` will not even compile when you switch your platform to WebGL. `UnityWebRequest` works fine with WebGL.
- `UnityWebRequest` is made to make it easier to download data in memory and convert the data into Unity resources such as `AudioClip`, `VideoClip`, `AssetBundle`, `Texture2D` and more. With `HttpClient`, you will have to write lots of codes just retrieve such data or probably have to save the data on the disc after receiving them just to be able to convert them into Unity resources form.
- Want to use SSL with `UnityWebRequest`? Good luck with that! You will only end up with the ambiguous *"unknown error"* error. When SSL is involved in your  `HttpClient` is the option.

With everything I just mentioned, you should port your code to use `UnityWebRequest` unless you are doing something that's not supported with `UnityWebRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a pity because we have the requirement to use SSL.

Comment: I've just tested with Unity 2018.2.7f1, and UnityWebRequest appears to work with HTTPS (SSL) now

Comment: @Buzzrick Yes, they added support for that recently(months ago). Although that's not mature enough to be used since I've seen many ssl issues with `UnityWebRequest`. Once it's mature enough I will edit this answer to mention that.

Comment: Do you know some list of platforms where `HttpClient` does not work? Thanks. E.g. I have heard from my collegue the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` does not work in Android simulator, but works on Android itself.

Comment: Actually, at least from 2018.3.0 you can actually compile HttpClient for WebGL but it still does not work since it relies on Threads which are not awailable in JS.

Comment: With Unity 2019.4.2f1, it seems that UnityWebRequest works with HTTPS.

Comment: I'll add that one of the difference between UnityWebRequest and HttpWebRequest comes also in the form of the data size and complexity received. You could say that HttpWebRequest is the stripped down version of UnityWebRequest. If you want a fast response and limit the data bandwidth to its minimum like loading just text and code references off the request (like for news text content), HttpWebRequest is better. If you want to load more complex data (like a an image to display in-game or loading a level's assembly) or if you want to use WebGL, UnityWebRequest is easier.