# REST Connection using UnityWebRequest via proxy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, proxy

I am trying to make a REST request to a server via proxy using UnityWebRequest. I have tried to use

```
Network.useProxy = true;
```

but this fails with the error

```
Cannot connect to destination host
```

`Network.useProxy` has been removed in Unity 2018.2.12. I am able to connect over Postman and curl. Can anybody confirm that UnityWebRequest does not support connection via proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it hasn't been deprecated, it wouldn't still work because Unity's `Network.useProxy` is used for the legacy networking system and the `UnityWebRequest` API is not part of that.

There is no support for proxy with `UnityWebRequest` and there is no plan to add support for this on Unity [`roadmap`](https://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap/). Vote for its support [here](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/unitywebrequest-proxy-support-slash-parity-with-www).

Your only workaround is to use one of the standard C# web request API such as  `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient`. They are supported in Unity. With `HttpWebRequest`, you can use proxy as below:

```
string proxyHost = "192.168.1.3";
int proxyPort = 8080;
string url = "http://YourUrl.com/blah";

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
```

Since this is not `UnityWebRequest`, you have to do that in another `Thread` to prevent blocking your game main Thread.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer - Do you know if C# web requests work across Unity target platforms?

Comment: Yes, it supports them all with the exception of WebGL platform. Nothing in the `System.Net` namespace is supported on the WebGL platform but that shouldn't be a problem if it's not your target platform. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160380/difference-between-httpclient-and-unitys-unitywebrequest-www-api) for other differences between them .