# Getting a parse error on Webgl build while same project works fine in editor

Tags: json, http, unity-game-engine, parsing, webgl

I'm doing a project on Unity Webgl and getting an error only when I build the project (in the editor it works fine). Basically I'm using a Jsonblob link to assign the parameters to a custom struct I made.

The error says: `Could not parse response {object}. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` {object} being the json I'm using in the jsonblob website.

The struct I'm using looks like this:

```
public struct GameSettings
{
    public String venueName { get; set; }
    public Monitor[] monitors { get; set; }
    public Flag[] flags { get; set; }
    public InformationMonitor[] informationMonitors { private get; set; }
    public Banner[] banners { get; set; }
    private const int MAX_MONITOR_LENGHT = 4;
}
```

While the functions where I get the data and assign it look like this:

```
public GameSettings gameSettings;

public void Awake()
{
    isRecovered = false;
    GetData((response) => {
        isRecovered = true;
        gameSettings = response;
    });
}

public async void GetData(System.Action<GameSettings> callback)
{
    var url = jsonURL;

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new JsonSerializationOptions());
    var result = await httpClient.Get<GameSettings>(url);
    callback(result);
}
```

As the error says, it seems to have trouble parsing the object, although I dont really understand why that is and especially why is it happening when the project works properly in the editor, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WebGL doesn't support multi-threading nor `async` the `HttpClient` is not supported on WebGL at all (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160380/difference-between-httpclient-and-unitys-unitywebrequest-www-api)).

You should rather use a [`UnityWebrequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) and for the JSON deserialization either use the built-in `JsonUtility` or `Newtonsoft Json.NET` which comes as a [Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) and preinstalled in latest versions.

E.g. something like

```
// In order to use the built-in serializer your types need to be [Serializable]
[Serializable]
public struct GameSettings
{
    private const int MAX_MONITOR_LENGHT = 4;

    // Note that all nested types also need to be [Serializable]
    // Also at least the built-in JsonUtility only supports fields by default, no properties
    // so either make them all fields or use Newtonsoft
    // or enforce serialization using the undocumented [field: SerializeField] for each property
    public string venueName;
    public Monitor[] monitors;
    public Flag[] flags;
    public InformationMonitor[] informationMonitors;
    public Banner[] banners; 
}

public GameSettings gameSettings;
public string jsonURL;

// Start can be a Coroutine, if it returns IEnumerator it is automatically 
// statred as a Coroutine by Unity
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    isRecovered = false;
    
    // you can simply yield another IEnumerator 
    yield return GetData();
}

private IEnumerator GetData()
{
    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get(jsonURL))
    {
        // Request and wait for the result
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"failed due to \"{www.error}\"", this);
            yield break;
        }

        // now this depends on how good your types are (de)serializable
        // either the built-in way
        gameSettings = JsonUtiltiy.FromJson<GameSettings>(www.downloadHandler.text);
        // or directly using Newtonsoft
        gameSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameSettings>(www.downloadHandler.text);


        isRecovered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it could work, though now I'm getting another error. This one says `ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid value.`  yet all the examples I've seen online use similar structs to mine. Since I'm not well versed with getting data from the web I don't really know how can I check if the issue is due to my Json or something else. The thing that bugs me the most is that the error is now always showing, so I don't know if Unity is just angry at the code formatting or something.

Comment: could you show your json content?

Comment: Okay, it looks like the Json I receive is empty (tested printing it to console). Maybe it has to do with var www and webRequest.SendWebRequest (I changed "webRequest" to www since Unity wasn't recognizing it)? The Json only has venueName, so maybe that's the issue right? My Json looks like this: `{
  "venueName": "Empty",
  "monitors": [],
  "flags": [],
  "informationMonitors": [],
  "banners": []
}`

Comment: To follow up, it was my mistake, the Json is working, although now I'm getting yet another error message, this one saying: `ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to call method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Monitor, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]::.cctor' for which no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated.` Is this caused by not serializing the arrays of monitor, flags and banner objects?

Comment: @SoraUdagawa This sounds related to [code stripping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html). In general, yes all the referenced types should also be `[Serializable]` .. and they also require to have a paramterless constructor!